# The good way to persist a FOSUser entity in cascade

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

I want to persist a User entity extends FOSUserBundle entity but an error occured :

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'username_canonical' cannot be null
```

How can I overload the persist function of my User entity to give the informations it needs ?

My User entity :

```
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
     protected $id;

     /**
      *
      * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="MyApp\MainBundle\Entity\Project")
      */
     private $project;
...
}
```

My Project entity:

```
class Structure
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer $master
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Uriae\UserBundle\Entity\User", cascade={"persist"})
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Type(type="Uriae\UserBundle\Entity\User")
     */
    private $master;
...
}
```

EDIT TO RESPONSE FractalizeR :

Do you mean i must set manually the usernameCanonical property after the persist ?

Actyally i have that after the form is sent in my controller :

```
$structure = new \Uriae\MainBundle\Entity\Structure();
if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
{
    $form->bindRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid())
    {
       $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
       $em->persist($structure);
       $em->flush();

       ...
    }
}
```

Do you mean I have to set manually the usernameCanonical property after the persist ? Or where/when ? But especially how ?

Comment: Have you set usernameCanonical property before persisting user?

Comment: @FractalizeR In fact, the FOSUser entity has many property cannot be null, and with this way to persist, FOSUser can't set the properties at the good value.
I seach a way to set this values without set manually the values and use the FOSUser functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're creating an instance of `Structure` and then trying to persist/flush... Doctrine2 is:

1. Realising that there is a relationship on `Structure` with `User` (each `Stucture` instance must have a `User` instance)
2. Because there is no `User` explicitly bound to the `Structure` instance, it tries to create an empty one.
3. The save operation on the `User`  fails, because there is no data (in this case, usernameCanonical string is empty)

What you must do is...

Before you save the `Structure`, add an instance of `User` to it... if you want to use the current user then use this

```
$user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
$structure->setMaster($user);
$em->persist($structure);
$em->flush();
```

Remember to include the `User` entity in your controller class (with the `use` statement).