# Persisting related entity

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm, symfony

Using FOSUserBundle, I'm trying to persist related entities. I extended User with a new entity called UserInfo. When persisting using cascade function:

user_id column in the related userinfo entity is not being filled with the value of id from user entity upon registration:

User entity:

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="re_user")
*/
class User extends BaseUser
{
...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="UserInfo", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    protected $userinfo;
```

User

```
class UserInfo
{
...

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="userinfo")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $user;

...
}
```

What id the correct way to persist related FOSUserBundle entities.

I hope I've explained it well, please let me know if I can clarify further.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009406/the-good-way-to-persist-a-fosuser-entity-in-cascade

Comment: Have you made any assignment to UserInfo::$user in your code?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by assignment but I've included part of my userinfo entity above where JoinColumn is with user_id referencing id from the User entity.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your setter method for $userinfo I can only guess, but I had a similar problem. In my situation the problem was that I did not set the related `mappedBy` property in the setter for the `inversedBy` property.

Try the following:

```
<?php
// ...
class User extends BaseUser {
  // ...
  public function setUserinfo(UserInfo $userinfo) {
    $userinfo->setUser($this);
    $this->userinfo = $userinfo;
  }
}
```